# event id : 7034 error, any solutions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am getting the following error every one hour in SharePoint. Not sure what exactly is happening. Any help will be appreciated. The error is below.

> Event Id:7034
>
> The SharePoint 2010 User Code Host service terminated unexpectedly. 
>   It has done this 462 time(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance\Disable Performance Counters`
is set to `1` this type of problem occurs.  The fix is to change it to `0` (or delete the registry key completely).

More details here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2021539
Another fellow suffer https://isharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/user-code-host-service-keeps-stopping/

Good Luck !